# Why does XOR and subtraction with the same HEX values give the same result?

Tags: math, assembly, hex, xor, subtraction

For example:

7A - 20   = 5A

7A XOR 20 = 5A

Of course, this will work the same using different values. Why does this occur exactly?

Comment: No, it doesn't "work the same using different values". For example, 4-1=3, but 4 xor 1 = 5. Is there something about XOR operations that you don't understand? Try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Comment: Try it with 0x5A & 0x20 as the two input values.

Comment: It is not even true with your example! Consider `20 - 7A` and `20 XOR 7A`

Answer (score 4):

**It's only the same if there are no borrows**,
i.e. no `0 - 1` at any bit-positions, only `1-0 = 1` or `1-1 = 0`.

That's the same as saying that the first operand (the minuend) has set bits everywhere the second operand (subtrahend) does.

i.e. if `x & y == y`, then `x-y == x^y`.

The simplest counter-example:

- `0 - 1 = 0xFF` - borrow propagates all the way to the top of the register.
- `0 ^ 1 = 0x01` - XOR is add-without-carry, it just flips the bits in one operand where a bit is set in the other operand.  (i.e. you could look at it as flipping no bits in `1`, leaving `1`.  Or as flipping the low bit in `0`, producing `1`.)

XOR is commutative (`x ^ y == y ^ x`), subtraction is not (`x-y` is usually different from `y-x`, except for special-case results like `0` or `0x80`)

Repeating XOR with the same value undoes it, e.g. `5A ^ 20 = 7A` flips the bit back on.
But repeating subtraction doesn't: `5A - 20 = 3A`.